# Fixing invalid UTF8 characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, iconv

I'm importing a txt file in to an sqlite database and then outputting those values in json format using php

`json_encode` fails, complaining about illegal characters. I tracked it down to the two accented characters in the string `terrains à bâtir` - this string renders fine when I open the file in Sublime but in Textedit the string is shown as `terrains ‡ b‚tir`

Some info about the file and its contents

- `file -i file.txt` tells me `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`
- `mb_detect_encoding()` on a valid string tells me it is `ASCII`
- `mb_detect_encoding()` on a invalid string tells me it is `UTF-8`
- `hexdump -C file.txt | grep terrains` shows the characters as dots:

`00a4eb30  7c 74 65 72 72 61 69 6e  73 20 e0 20 62 e2 74 69  ||terrains . b.ti|`

- `cat file.txt | tail -c +1671338 | head -c 20` shows the characters as � and they appear in my sqlite GUI the same way.

  `ns � b�tir|11111|AAA`

I know it's possible to use iconv to "fix" this using the TRANSLIT or IGNORE options but then I end up with something different than what it's supposed to be.

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($row[2]);
if($encoding !== 'ASCII') {
    $enc = mb_detect_encoding($row[2]);
    $converted = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', $row[2]);
    print_r($converted);
}
```

Using `IGNORE` (obviously) outputs `terrains  btir` and with TRANSLIT the method complains about `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`

**My goal is to revert these characters to their proper accented form, using PHP. How can I do this?** I'm guessing the hexdump output provides some clues, but I can't figure out which bytes are the problematic ones or how to fix them.

Comment: Guessing and programs/functions that guess will not lead to success. Start with, what is the character encoding of the file? (It is not ASCII if you say the proper interpretation of the bytes includes à and â.)

Comment: @TomBlodget file -i file.txt tells me charset=us-ascii. Is there another way I can check? I'm assuming that whoever authored the file (from a govt public dataset) made some mistakes wrt encoding

Comment: `file` saying that means it compatible with just about every one except UTF-16, UTF-32 and EBCDIC. But that the characters with diacritics are not on the file! Where do they come from?

Comment: Data's coming from a govt public data set. There are other accents in the file that render file so it's probably just badly authored. I found a workaround. Post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know what the answer is. You would be the best person to write it.